# I am using meta tag for image preview , it is working correct on localhost, but when sharing the link of live site it doesn't preview anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I am using meta tag for image preview in react , it is working correct on localhost, but when sharing the link of live site  it doesn't preview anything? I have check many time, and in linkedin it is showing that image, title and description are not available ?

```
<Seo title={`Meet ${basicCreatorInfo?.name} `}
    description={basicCreatorInfo?.tagLine}
    imgUrl={basicCreatorInfo?.profile}
  />
```

this is how i am passing SEO .

```
<meta property="og:title" content={title} />
  <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
  <meta property="og:image" content={imgUrl} />
```

and how i am receiving it.

I have tried ,many ways but nothing works. I want to preview the image, title description when link is shared.